# How to create a string or formula containing double quotes in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I construct the following string in an Excel formula:

> Maurice "The Rocket" Richard

If I'm using single quotes, it's trivial: `="Maurice 'The Rocket' Richard"` but what about double quotes?

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Have you tried escaping with an additional double-quote? By escaping a character, you are telling Excel to treat the " character as literal text.

```sql
= "Maurice ""The Rocket"" Richard"
```

Answer (score 180):

Alternatively, you can use the `CHAR` function:

```
= "Maurice " & CHAR(34) & "Rocket" & CHAR(34) & " Richard"
```

Comment: This works more consistently for me than `""` Maybe it's just because I have Mac Excel 2011

Comment: @Ivanoats: Nope, it's not a Mac thing (using Windows here) - this _does_ work more consistently; in my case, concatenating using `&` with a double quote just before or just after the ampersand didn't work using the double-double-quote method.

Comment: Works more consistently for me, as I often need to wrap quotation marks around a complicated string built up of multiple concatenated fields with interspersed punctuation. In my most recent case, to come up with something like this: "NameOfLocation, Street Address, City, State Zip"

Answer (score 26):

Three double quotes: `" " " x " " "` = `"x"` Excel will auto change to one double quote. e.g.:

```
=CONCATENATE("""x"""," hi")
```

= "x" hi

Comment: If this would be true, then please elaborate on the outcome of =concatenate("a"""b"). According to your observation, the outcome would be a"b. This is not the case. In fact this expression will not even be accepted by Excel.

Comment: you forgot the comma

Comment: The outer quotes in your example are just starting and ending the string.  "" creates a quote character, not """.

Comment: *Two* double-quotes will auto change to one double-quote: `=CONCATENATE("<""x"">"," hi")` -> `<"x"> hi`

Answer (score 8):

In the event that you need to do this with JSON:

```
=CONCATENATE("'{""service"": { ""field"": "&A2&"}}'")
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally helped me! I was struggling to properly format a JSON array in my cells.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed :)

Answer (score 7):

I use a function for this (if the workbook already has VBA).

```
Function Quote(inputText As String) As String
  Quote = Chr(34) & inputText & Chr(34)
End Function
```

This is from Sue Mosher's book "Microsoft Outlook Programming". Then your formula would be:

`="Maurice "&Quote("Rocket")&" Richard"`

This is similar to what [Dave DuPlantis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218474/190829) posted.

Answer (score 4):

Use  chr(34)
Code:

```
    Joe = "Hi there, " & Chr(34) & "Joe" & Chr(34)
    ActiveCell.Value = Joe
```

Result:

```
    Hi there, "joe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate `"` as a ceparate cell:

```
    A |   B   | C | D
1   " | text  | " | =CONCATENATE(A1; B1; C1);

D1 displays "text"
```

Answer (score 1):

will this work for macros using `.Formula = "=THEFORMULAFUNCTION("STUFF")"`
so it would be like:
will this work for macros using `.Formula = "=THEFORMULAFUNCTION(CHAR(34) & STUFF & CHAR(34))"`

Comment: Don't know if this particular syntax is available in VBA. Give it a try.

Comment: Looks like a yes: http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/575414-quotes-double-quotes-where-when-use-them

Answer (score 1):

Returning an empty or zero-length string (e.g. `""`) to make a cell appear blank is a common practise in a worksheet formula but recreating that option when inserting the formula through the [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) property in VBA is unwieldy due to the necessity of having to double-up the double-quote characters within a quoted string.

The worksheet's native [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) can produce the same result without using quotes.

```
'formula to insert into C1 - =IF(A1<>"", B1, "")
range("C1").formula = "=IF(A1<>"""", B1, """")"         '<~quote chars doubled up
range("C1").formula = "=IF(A1<>TEXT(,), B1, TEXT(,))"   '<~with TEXT(,) instead
```

To my eye, using `TEXT(,)` in place of `""` cleans up even a simple formula like the one above. The benefits become increasingly significant when used in more complicated formulas like the practise of appending an empty string to a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to avoid returning a zero to the cell when a lookup results in a blank or returning an empty string on no-match with [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5).

```
'formula to insert into D1 - =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)&"", "")
range("D1").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)&"""", """")"
range("D1").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)&TEXT(,), TEXT(,))"
```

With `TEXT(,)` replacing the old `""` method of delivering an empty string, you might get to stop using an abacus to determine whether you have the right number of quote characters in a formula string.

Answer (score 1):

```
="Maurice "&"""TheRocker"""&" Richard"
```

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Function**

1)  .Formula = "=""THEFORMULAFUNCTION ""&(CHAR(34) & ""STUFF"" & CHAR(34))"

2)  .Formula = "THEFORMULAFUNCTION ""STUFF"""

The first method uses vba to write a formula in a cell which results in the calculated value:

```
 THEFORMULAFUNCTION "STUFF"
```

The second method uses vba to write a string in a cell which results in the value:

```
 THEFORMULAFUNCTION "STUFF"
```

**Excel Result/Formula**

1) ="THEFORMULAFUNCTION "&(CHAR(34) & "STUFF" & CHAR(34))

2) THEFORMULAFUNCTION "STUFF"

Answer (score -1):

There is another way, though more for " How can I construct the following string in an Excel formula: "Maurice "The Rocket" Richard" " than " How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas? ", which is simply to use two single quotes:

[image: SO216616 example]

On the left is Calibri snipped from an Excel worksheet and on the right a snip from a VBA window.
In my view escaping as mentioned by @YonahW wins 'hands down' but two single quotes is no more typing than two doubles and the difference is reasonably apparent in VBA without additional keystrokes while, potentially, not noticeable in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

The following formula works on Excel as well as Numbers (on MAC) :

```
= "Maurice " & """" & "The Rocket" & """" & " Richard"
```

Use & """" & to get a single double quote surrounding your string.

Comment: This is no different to the accepted answer, and add no additional value