# How to search for " in string - EXCEL

Tags: excel

This is a tricky one I am stuck on. In Excel 2010 I want to search a string for the character `"`. I am using the formula

```
=FIND(A1,"text", 1)
```

which will return a number (starting position) of "text" in A1 string, or an error if not found.

How to search for `"` in the formula?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: try `=FIND(A1,"\"", 1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas)

Comment: also google + excel escape quotes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try amending your formula to search for Char(34), think this will help with readability instead of having 10,000 quotes in your formula.

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND(CHAR(34),A1))
```

Comment: Amen!  Readability is just as important as functionality.

Answer (score 15):

You use a bunch of `"` until Excel understands it has to look for one :)

```
=FIND("""", A1)
```

Explanation:
Between the outermost quotes, you have `""`. The first quote is used to escape the second quote so that `""` in between quotes means a single double quote.

Also, you can drop the 1 at the end if you want to check the whole string.

Note that it's find character, into cell. Or use `CHAR(34)` which is the equivalent of a quote:

```
=FIND(CHAR(34), A1)
```

Comment: You use a bunch of " until Excel understands??? This is not magic: doubling quotes is way Excel quotes them. Also, you can drop the 1 at the end if you want to check the whole string??? Excel may correct it well or not!!! -1 for laziness

Comment: @LS_dev The bunch of `"` was a joke, okay? Anyone could get confused by the sheer number of `"` in a formula. Also, of course you can drop the 1 at the end, because `1` means start from character 1, which is basically what `FIND(find_text, within_text)` does. Excel does not correct it, Excel takes 1 as the default as this is how it works. Btw, check your own formula, it returns `#VALUE`.

Comment: Hum... Ok, misunderstood "1 at end" point (understood "removing one quote at end"). But you still didn't give a clear explanation. Can't remove downvote now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use search too

```
=SEARCH("""";A1)
```

[image]

Comment: why does this work? shouldn't it find an instance of two double quotes next to each other.  This behaviour is very confusing on Excel's part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using the search and replace function use ~
to search for " / "
use ~" / ~"
~ work for any odd character

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I wanted Excel to select the part of a sentence that was -- I thought -- between quotation marks `" "` (or `CHAR(34)` in excel) while in fact it was between a

Left double quotation mark  (or `CHAR(147)` in excel) “

and a

Right double quotation mark (or `CHAR(148)` in excel)  ”

In cell A1 I had a text string that went pretty much as follows:

blablablabla “None of the sectors reported in 2000 blablabla”

I wanted Excel to select the only part I was interested in which was :

-->  None of the sectors reported in 2000  <--

You can use this formula:
`=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"“"),CHAR(148),)`

For the sake of a more comprehensive example here I used "“" in the formula `TEXTAFTER(A1,"“")`  but I could have used `TEXTAFTER(A1,CHAR(147)`

Similarly with the TEXTBEFORE formula where I used CHAR(148), but I could have used "”" instead.

Anyway just make sure you don't get confused with “ ” (right and left double quotation marks)  and " " (quotation mark).

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of escaping quotes inside strings, in Excel formulas is doubling them:

```
=FIND(A1, """")
```

will return first quote found in <kbd>A1</kbd> (or error if not found).