# How to determine if a cell formula contains Constants?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

When debugging or Quality Checking an Excel report at work I have found that the problem was because of text being hard coded inside a formula. I have heard this as being a Constant and Formula mixed cell.

Here are examples of what I see.

Constant =`100`

Constant =`Facility`

Formula cell `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH($A7&$B7&C$2,Data!$4:$4,0),,,$A$2))`

Mixed cell `=INDIRECT("Data!"&ADDRESS(5,MATCH($A7&$B7&C$2,Data!$4:$4,0)))`

`"Data!"` is the Constant in the mixed cell, in this case the sheet name. If that sheet name ever changed, the formula would break. I have found and am using two conditional formats to highlight cells that are Constants and those that are formulas using this ["Identify formulas using Conditional Formatting"](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip045.htm). I need to come up with a way to format those cells which contain these Constants inside of formulas.

I have [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847431/how-to-search-for-in-string-excel) and tried using `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(CHAR(34),A1,1)),TRUE,FALSE)` and `FIND()` to see if I could check if a cell had double quotes inside of it, but the SEARCH() returns `FALSE` since it is looking at the cells value and not it's contents. It returns `TRUE` if the cell contains `"Constant"` but if it is a formula it returns `FALSE`, such as if the cell contains `="Constant"`.

How can I find Constants inside formulas across a whole worksheet or workbook?

### EDIT*

Thanks to Sidd's code below I have made a function in a module I can use in conditional formatting to at least highlight cells that contain quotes inside the cells.

```
Function FormulaHasQuotes(aCell)

  If InStr(1, aCell.Formula, """") Then
      FormulaHasQuotes = True
  Else
      FormulaHasQuotes = False
  End If

End Function
```

[image: FormulaHasQuotes Conditional formatting pic]

Comment: Its complex and not fool-proof, you need to parse the formula. My addin `Mappit!` uses regular expressions to indentify constants inf formulae,but in the case above it would pick out the `5` not `Data!` which is really a location rather than a constant.

Comment: Very Impressive addin thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your sheet looks like this.

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, FRange As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find all the cells which have formula
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FRange = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not FRange Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Check for " in the cell's formula
            For Each aCell In FRange
                If InStr(1, aCell.Formula, """") Then
                    Debug.Print "Cell " & aCell.Address; " has a constant"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When you run the above code, you get this output

```
Cell $A$2 has a constant
Cell $A$5 has a constant
```

Note: I have shown you how to do it for a sheet, i am sure you can replicate it for all sheets in a workbook?

Comment: Thats neat. But doesn't 3 and 4 contain constants too?

Comment: @Steve: As per OP, anything that is within QUOTES is a constant. Now `Constant` here is not be confused with the actual Constants like `1`, `24` etc... At least that is what I have understood from the question...

Comment: Very first example was **Constant =100**

Comment: @Steve: True. But I don't see it being used in a formula in OP's post. What I see however is `if I could check if a cell had double quotes inside of it...` Lets wait for OP to clarify :)

Comment: Thank you Sidd, this will help me in most if not all situations. However Steve does have a point that the Address formula contains the constant `5` I am not sure if there is a way to show if the cell contains a hard coded number like that `5`.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout, I modified your Sub to be a function so I could use it in conditional formatting and it works to highlight cells that contain quotes inside of them. Thank you! +1, edited my question to show my function.

Answer (score 0):

Only very lightly tested...

For example will not handle "string" constants which contain embedded `"`

```
Sub Tester()

'add reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
Dim regxnum As New RegExp, regexpchar As New RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection, m As Match

Dim rngF As Range, c As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngF = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngF Is Nothing Then

        regxnum.Pattern = "[^A-Z$](-?\d{1,}\.?\d{0,})"
        regxnum.Global = True

        regexpchar.Pattern = "(""[^""]{0,}"")"
        regexpchar.Global = True

        For Each c In rngF.Cells
            Debug.Print c.Formula
            Set matches = regxnum.Execute(c.Formula)

            For Each m In matches
                    Debug.Print c.Parent.Name, c.Address(), m.SubMatches(0)
            Next m

            Set matches = regexpchar.Execute(c.Formula)
            For Each m In matches
                    Debug.Print c.Parent.Name, c.Address(), m.SubMatches(0)
            Next m

        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```