# Highlight cells in selection that contain formulas with constants

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a budget in excel 2007.  It was written by someone else and contains many sheets and many formulas.  I am trying to make the spreadsheet more efficient by creating an Input worksheet where all/most constants would be entered.  To help with this process, I would like to be able to highlight all formulas that contain constants as well as highlight all constants (not in formulas) within my selection.  Or, if easier, the opposite, highlight all formulas that do not contain constants within my selection.  I am mainly dealing with numbers, not text.

Here are examples of formulas(=) with **constants** and just **constants**:

1. =**82000**-**50000**
2. =$A$2-**50000**
3. =A2-**50000**
4. =F133***.05**
5. 50000

Here are examples of formulas(=) that do not contain constants:

1. =SUM(E8:P8)
2. =$C$51*'Servicing Detail'!$E$181
3. =K152

The closest answer I could find to my question was here: [How to determine if a cell formula contains Constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058246/how-to-determine-if-a-cell-formula-contains-constants/19058564#19058564?newreg=9e3269b7567a425db42e3daa97dce817). But I believe this post to be specific to finding quotations within a formula as Siddharth Rout clarified in his last comment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.  (This is my first post and hope that I have formatted correctly. Apologies in advance)

Comment: You can use the `IsRef` function to determine whether a cell contains reference to another cell. At first glance I would expect that to work, but I would NOT consider a cell reference like `$A$2` to be a "constant" the way you have assumed, so it may not work for your purposes.

Comment: Do you have a formal definition of what you consider to be a constant and what you do not? That would be the first place to start. From your list, I'm not sure what criteria you're using to separate constants/non constants...

Comment: to have a quick look inside cell you can just press `Ctrl + ~` to switch between formulas and values.

Comment: You would probably need a full blown parser to check every cell ... take apart whats in the cell, check if its a reference... quite a task to write (VBA)

Comment: If all your contants are numeric, and you don't need to account for names which reference fixed values, then a regular expression which checks for numeric values might work.  Of course, you'd also need to account for whether the previous owner also had *some* contants stored in cells...

Comment: I thought I would have a solution but in fact in does not work in all cases. The idea is to use the SPLIT function in VBA to parse a formula into components and test if at least one component is numeric. Probably feasible with a bit of investigation.

Comment: @DavidZemens - In my examples, the bold portion is the constant.  $A$2 would not be a constant.

Comment: @nwhaught - I would use the excel glossary definition for constant:  A value that is not calculated. For example, the number 210 and the text "Quarterly Earnings" are constants.

Comment: According to your definition, a constant is a numeric variable or a text string between double quotes. Delimiters inside a formula are mathematical operators (e.g. +, -, *, ...) or the list separator or a parenthesis. So you need to test if the first component of a formula is either a numeric constant or a text string. If yes, your test is positive. If not, you have to test the second component. And so one until all components have been tested. Add a control to test only cells with formulas. See my answer below for an example edited to take account of text strings as constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse formulas using the SPLIT function in VBA. E.g. the code below works for the examples you have given. Returns TRUE if formula contains constants, returns N/A if it is not a formula and FALSE otherwise.

Probably you have to adapt a little bit so it works in all cases, but it's a good starting point.

```
Function HasConstant(r As Range) As Variant

Application.Volatile

Dim formula As String
Dim delimiters() As String
Dim delimiter As Variant
Dim Components() As String
Dim component As Variant
Dim chars As Integer

delimiters() = Split("+ - * / = & ( ) ,")

If r.HasFormula Then

    formula = Right(r.formula, Len(r.formula) - 1)

    Do Until formula = ""

        chars = Len(formula)
        component = formula

        For Each delimiter In delimiters

            Components = Split(formula, delimiter)

            If Len(Components(0)) < chars And Len(Components(0)) > 0 Then
                component = Components(0)
                chars = Len(component)
            End If

        Next

        If IsNumeric(Replace(component, ".", Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))) Then 'IsNumeric(component)
            HasConstant = True
            Exit Function
        ElseIf Left(CStr(component), 1) = Chr(34) And Right(CStr(component), 1) = Chr(34) Then
            HasConstant = True
            Exit Function
        End If

        If chars < Len(formula) Then
            formula = Right(formula, Len(formula) - chars - 1)
        Else
            formula = ""
        End If

    Loop

Else

    HasConstant = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function

End If

HasConstant = False

End Function
```

Example:

[image]