# how to add a test for non-black cells using `FormulaR1C1' in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert the following equation into a sheet:

```
=COUNTIFS(email_logs_output.csv!$AB$2:$AB$26731, _
                            usersFullOutput.csv!S26, _
                            email_logs_output.csv!$R$2:$R$26731, _
                            "<>"&"", _
                            email_logs_output.csv!$H$2:$H$26731, _
                            "gift*")
```

I'm getting stuck at the criteria `"<>"&""`.  Here's what I have:

```
With Worksheets(users_sheet)
    equation_range.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & emails_sheet & "!R2C" & email_col & ":R" & rows_email & "C" & email_col & " , RC[" & col_back & "], " _
                                   & emails_sheet & "!R2C18:R" & rows_email & "C18, "" " <> " & "" "")"
End With
```

When I run it, all I get is `TRUE` in every cell in `equation_range`.

How do I get the equation to include `"<>"&""`?

Comment: The escape character for quotation marks in a string is double quotes (2 quotes inside of quotes = 1 quote) so `"<>"""""` http://stackoverflow.com/a/216623/1274820

Comment: When I run the code with `...C18, " <> """"")"` I get `TRUE` in every cell in the range.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried this as well: `...C18, """ <> "" & """"")"`, and I still get True in every cell in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried one formula and this works
`[a1].FormulaR1C1 = "=countif(R1C3,""<>"" & ""a"")"`
So in your case
`...C18,""<>"" & "" "")"`

---

### Notes

Basicaly, whenever you have "*text*" in your formula just put ""*text*"" and that should do the trick.

Another thing : Beware of the "autospreading" of the code in VBA environment. Check for non wanted spaces added automaticaly where you may not want them.

Comment: Using your answer I came up with `...C18, ""<>""&"""")"`.  It's what your wrote, but with no spaces.  Per your comment, the spaces make a difference.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: @dwstein Ou, OK. I thought you actually want to check if the cell has a *space*. My bad, but glad it helped.