# Excel Conditional formula, Formula1 parameter with double quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set the following formula in the conditional formula using *VBA*. I tried all different ways like doubling the double quote and `Chr(34)`. Please help.

```
vFormula = "=OR(TEXT(B$2,"ddd")="Sat",TEXT(B$2,"ddd")="Sun")"
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=vFormula
```

What is the correct way to pass the `Formula1` parameter which contains double quotes?

Comment: Both methods [should work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas).

Comment: Try `vFormula = "=OR(TEXT(B$2,""ddd"")=""Sat"",TEXT(B$2,""ddd"")=""Sun"")"`. You need to double up double-quote characters within a quoted string.

Comment: Try `=WEEKDAY(B$2, 2)>5`

Comment: why those didn't work for you? have you received error message, or unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your purposes:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=OR(TEXT(R2C[-3],""ddd"")=""Sat"",TEXT(R2C[-3],""ddd"")=""Sun"")"
```

You would just have to change the relative cell reference.

Regards,

Comment: It seems the formula is actually intended as the `Formula1` parameter in the creation of a CF rule but your suggestion would work. xlR1C1 style formulas can be shoveled into the Formula1 parameter.

Comment: @nbayly       your solution worked for few conditions. However, I have the below condition. <br> rFormula = "=AND("POS"=LEFT($A3,3),COUNTIFS($AY$53:$AY$200,"<=" & B$2,$BB$53:$BB$200,">=" & B$2,$BE$53:$BE$200,$A3)=1)"  <br>  rFormula1 = Application.ConvertFormula(rFormula, 1, , 1) gives me <br> "=AND("POS"=LEFT(R3C1,3),COUNTIFS(R53C51:R200C51,"<=" & R2C2,R53C54:R200C54,">=" & R2C2,R53C57:R200C57,R3C1)=1)" <br> .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=rFormula1 <br> is throwing error