# Excel function to combine cells and double quotes

Tags: excel, function

I currently have a spreadsheet with the following format

```
A1 = <Name> 
B1 = <Email>
C1 = New-MailContact
D1 = '-Name
E1 = '-ExternalEmailAddress
F1 = =(C1&" "&D1&" ""&A1&"" "&E1&" ""&B1&""")
```

My issue is that my F1 column results in the following output:

```
New-MailContact -Name "&A1&" -ExternalEmailAddress "&B1&"
```

Can someone please help me to fix the A1 and B1 records so they show up as the actual name and email rather than A1 and B1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of extra quotes

```
=C1 & " " & D1 & " " & A1 & " " & E1 & " " & B1
```

should display the data concatenated.

If you want the name or other fields to be quoted, for every quote you want add two quotes in the string:

```
= """" & C1 & """"
```

will display `New-MailContact` in quotes, like this `"New-MailContact"`

See this as `" "" "` where the outside quotes are to denote it as a string, and the two quotes inside are for displaying the one `"`

So if you need name and email (`A1` and `B1`) quoted, you need

```
=C1 & " " & D1 & " """ & A1 & """ " & E1 & " """ & B1 & """"
```

[More examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas).

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII code for a double-quote character is 22 hex or 34 dec. The ASCII character code for a space is 20 hex or 32 dec.

```
=C1&CHAR(32)&D1&CHAR(32)&CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(32)&E1&CHAR(32)&CHAR(34)&B1&CHAR(34)
'alternate with CONCATENATE
=CONCATENATE(C1, CHAR(32), D1, CHAR(32), CHAR(34), A1, CHAR(34), CHAR(32), E1, CHAR(32), CHAR(34), B1, CHAR(34))
'alternate with Office 365's TEXTJOIN¹
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(32), FALSE, C1, D1, CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34), E1, CHAR(34)&B1&CHAR(34))
```

---

¹ The [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) was introduced with Excel 2016 with Office 365 or Excel Online.

[image: char_34]