# Runtime error 1004 when inserting formula into cell VBA Excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-formula

I am getting runtime error 1004 when trying to insert a formula into a cell in VBA.

In my excel sheet I have a date in column A and a stock ticker in row 1 starting in column B every 3 columns, so B, E, H etc.

In cell C2 I am trying to divide the value in B2 by the value in row 2 under the column heading "FTSE". Putting this formula into the cell directly works:

```
=IFERROR(B2/(VLOOKUP($A2,$A$2:$GMQ$261,MATCH("FTSE",$B$1:$GMQ$1,0)+1,FALSE)),"")
```

I am trying to do this using vba. This is the code I have:

```
Sub InsertFormula()

   Range("C2").Select
   ActiveCell.Formula = _
   "=IFERROR(B2/(VLOOKUP($A2,$A$2:$GMQ$261,MATCH(""FTSE"",$B$1:$GMQ$1,0)+1,FALSE)),"")"

End Sub
```

Comment: Remember to "double-up" on that final pair of double-quotes!

Comment: gary is right... the formula needs to be `"=IFERROR(B2/(VLOOKUP($A2,$A$2:$GMQ$261,MATCH(""FTSE"",$B$1:$GMQ$1,0)+1,FALSE)),"""")"` (you missed the "" for the error-part to double up)

Comment: @Ralph  I posted it as a comment because I was using a cell phone and could not completely test an alternative line of code.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the confusion generated by double-double-quotes¹ with the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) used as `TEXT(,)`. This returns a zero-length string just as `""` does and there are no quotes to double up like `""""`.

```
Range("C2").Formula = _
 "=IFERROR(B2/(VLOOKUP($A2, $A$2:$GMQ$261, MATCH(""FTSE"", $B$1:$GMQ$1 ,0)+1, FALSE)), TEXT(,))"
'without the offset and subsequent adjustment with full column references
Range("C2").Formula = _
 "=IFERROR(B2/VLOOKUP($A2, $A:$GMQ, MATCH(""FTSE"", $1:$1 ,0), FALSE), TEXT(,))"
```

---

¹ <sub>See **[How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas/36169987#36169987)** for more examples.</sub>

Comment: Oh woah, thanks for that tip, I'll have to use that.