# Nested strings for text(,format) conversion

Tags: excel, string, text, nested, format

How do you use Text() with a format that has a string inside it ?

```
=TEXT(A1,"Comfi+"#0"(JO)";"Comfi-"#0"(JO)")
```

Tried """ both the inner string :

```
 =TEXT(A1," """Comfi+"""#0"""(JO)""";"""Comfi-"""#0"(JO)""" ")
```

Same result with &char(34)&

Similar issue here, but I couldn't transpose the solution to my problem : [How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas)

> **Post Solution edit :**
>
> Building an almanac/calendar with the following (now fixed)formula :
>
> ```
> =CONCATENATE(
>     TEXT(Format!K25,"d"),
>     "              J+",
>     Format!S25,
>     "               ",
>     TEXT(Format!AA25,"""Comfi+""#0""(JO)"";""Comfi-""#0""(JO)"""),
>     "               ",
>     Format!AI25
> )
> ```
>
> Giving the following output in each cell :
>
> ```
>            9
>         J+70               
> Comfi+21(JO)               
>          CRG
> ```

Comment: Can you show the final string you want?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld solved it ! The final string looks like "Comfi+10JO" it's an extract of a larger concatenate() with various formats (date, numbers, string)

Comment: @Wiglie thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got too many quotation marks inside:

```
=TEXT(A1,"""Comfi+""#0""(JO)"";""Comfi-""#0""(JO)""")
```

You were tripling many of the inside quotation marks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally, doubling up double-quotes within a quoted string is something I try to avoid at all costs. You can 'escape' the text into literals with a backslash.

```
=TEXT(A1,"\C\o\m\f\i+#0\(\J\O\);\C\o\m\f\i-#0\(\J\O\)")
'alternately
="Comfi"&text(a1, "+#0;-#0")&"(JO)"
```

Not all of those actually need to be escaped; only reserved characters. However, I usually escape them all and let Excel sort them out.

[image]

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I'm only showing the process.