# how to concatenate a string and cell value in excel if the string already has quotes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

="python sql.py  --table process --query-type UPDATE --column-value active='N' --where ""pid=9999 and data_id=""&A1&"""

I need A1 to be whatever is in cell A1 but the formula is treating it as a part of the string

the final output should be

python sql.py  --table process --query-type UPDATE --column-value active='N' --where "pid=9999 and data_id=0001"

Comment: How to create strings containing double quotes in Excel formulas? https://stackoverflow.com/q/216616/992406]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
="python sql.py --table process --query-type UPDATE --column-value active='N' --where ""pid=9999 and data_id="&A1&""""
```