# Adding quotes around cell in formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that will help me in creating sql query

In Excel this is what I have written down:-

> =CONCATENATE("UPDATE T_KeyAttribute set description=",B3," WHERE KeyName=",A3)

This gives me for example:-

[image]

How can I add quotes around the values of B3 and A3 (i.e. around their text values)

Comment: Put the double quotes inside double quotes as a piece of text.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: So using & I would do =“””&B3&”””

Comment: @SolarMike so I did, =CONCATENATE("UPDATE T_KeyAttribute set description=","""&B2&"""," WHERE KeyName=",A2). Doesn't work

Comment: Don’t mix concatenate and &. & does do concatenation but uses fewer characters.

Comment: @SolarMike so I need not do any formula?
Just use &?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="UPDATE T_KeyAttribute SET description ='"&B3&"' WHERE KeyName = '"&A3&"'"
```

This will return:

```
UPDATE T_KeyAttribute SET description = 'Text1' WHERE KeyName = 'Text2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using `CHAR(34)`. You might find other strategies that you can use for your specific situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216616/how-to-create-strings-containing-double-quotes-in-excel-formulas)

```
="UPDATE T_KeyAttribute set description="&
CHAR(34)&B4&CHAR(34)&
" WHERE KeyName="&
CHAR(34)&A4&CHAR(34)
```